# PHP DateTime for .NET developers

Tags: php, .net, datetime

PHP's DateTime class has the two methods add() and sub() to add or subtract a time span from a DateTime object. This looks very familiar to me, in .NET I can do the same thing. But once I tried it, it did very strange things. I found out that in PHP, those methods will modify the object itself. This is not documented and the return value type indicates otherwise. Okay, so in some scenarios I need three lines of code instead of one, plus an additional local variable. But then PHP5's copy by reference model comes into play, too. Just copying the object isn't enough, you need to explicitly clone it to not accidently modify the original instance still. So here's the C# code:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
...
if (date < today.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(7)) ...
```

Here's the PHP equivalent:

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
...
$then = clone $today;
$then->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
if ($date < $then) ...
```

(I keep a copy of today to have the same time for all calculations during the method runtime. I've seen it often enough that seconds or larger time units change in that time...)

Is this it in PHP? I need to write a wrapper class for that if there's no better solution! Or I'll just stay with the good ol' time() function and just use DateTime for easier parsing of the ISO date I get from the database.

```
$today = time() % 86400;
...
if ($date < $today + 7 * 86400) ...
```

Time zones not regarded in these examples.

Update: I just found out that I can use the strtotime() function as well for parsing such dates. So what's the use for a DateTime class in PHP after all if it's so complicated to use?

Update^2: I noticed that my $today = ... thing above is garbage. Well, please just imagine some correct way of getting 'today' there instead...

Comment: Um, re "This is not documented".... `DateTime::add — Adds an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds to a DateTime object`

Comment: Yes, adds some time and returns the new value - this is my understanding of it. And there's nothing else that clarifies it. Modifying the instance is totally impractical. Especially if it requires such effort to avoid it.

Comment: It *does* say `Returns the DateTime object for method chaining`. That implies it's the original object. But I agree, it's not very practical sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you will definitely have to make a clone of the object. There does not seem to be a way to create a copy of the DateTime object any other way.

As far as I can see,  you could save one line:

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
...
$then = clone $today;
if ($then->add(new DateInterval('P7D')) < $then) ...
```

I agree this isn't perfect. But do stick with `DateTime` nevertheless - write a helper class if need be. It is *way* superior to the old date functions: It doesn't have the year 2038 bug, and it makes dealing with time zones much, much easiert.

Comment: The idea of a method on DateTime returning a modified copy instead of modifying the original is really a .NET quirk - most of the time in any other language adding or subtracting a value is going to modify the original. Sometimes you need to modify the original and sometimes you need to modify a copy.

Comment: Well, most of the time it was really practical to get a modified copy of the DateTime. And if I need to modify the original, I can always assign the result to the same variable. In .NET, DateTime is a struct, not a class, which means that it's copied by value anyway, saving me an explicit clone operation.